# Можно ли понять из какого браузера было осуществлено копирование?

Tags: c#, .net

Например, если копировать из IE буфер выглядит по одному, а если копировать что-то со страницы через Chrome, то HTML в буфере будет выглядеть по другому=> может потребоваться его обрабатывать иначе из-за особенностей браузера.

Просто, программа должна залезть в буфер и вытянуть оттуда Html, а потом его обработать.

Comment: что значит _копировать из IE_ и _копировать со страницы_?

Comment: Обычная вставка или разширеная? Копирующая сторона может несколько форматов вставки поддерживать. CF_TEXT - простейший формат, но есть у некоторых RTF-поддержка и другие.

Comment: @Grundy, пропустил слово Chrome

Comment: @nick_n_a, вставка не имеет значения. Я ручками беру из буфера данные в Html формате и делаю обработку.

Comment: Буфер обмена вы получаете в c# так? Даже если вы в ворд вставляете - разные браузеры по разному делают буфер обмена. Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону разширеный буфер обмена, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: С вашей страницы (которую вы контролируете как разработчик), или с любой?

Comment: @eastwing, любая.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Тогда предлагаю копать в сторону средств ОС (Win32 API, например)

Comment: В win api есть функция `GetClipboardOwner`, которая может вернуть окошко, последним поместившее что-либо в буфер обмена. А вообще логичнее преобразование производить, исходя из самих данных, а не кто их разместил. Проверяется соответствие данных каким-то шаблонам/сигнатурам и выбирается соответствующее преобразование.

Comment: @Sergey, а можно пример с использованием GetClipboardOwner? Что-то получаю хэндл, а дальше не понимаю, что с ним дальше делать=(

Comment: Возможно по классу окна можно догадаться, что за браузер. Через handle как раз получить интересные свойства. Имя класса например обычно у всех разное: `GetClassName(hwnd, ...)`. Наверное можно получить процесс, которому принадлежит окошко: chrom-у.exe или ie.exe

Comment: @iluxa1810 стоп, картинку понятно как копировать, понятно как копировать текст.Но как вы хотите с помощью буфера копировать хтмл с браузера? Разница между буферами действительно есть или вы только предполагаете(с разных браузеров)?

Comment: @FORTRAN, разница есть. Ее можно увидеть, использовав утилиту FreeClipViewer.

Comment: @Sergey, в принципе сработало, но печально, что если окно закрыть, то вся инфа о владельце пропадает=(

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать следующим образом:

```
static bool CopiedFromIE()
{
    return Clipboard.ContainsData("msSourceUrl");
}
```